# path of a script from another one

Tags: php, path

I have this structure:

```
-folder1
   -folder2
      -script1.php
   -folder3
      -script2.php
```

Now I'm trying to call `script1` from `script2`:

```
// script2.php
file_get_contents(" what path ? ");
```

**Note:** This path doesn't work `/folder1/folder2/script1.php/`. I can do that by writing it plus domain name like this:

```
http://example.com/folder1/folder2/script1.php/
```

But I want to know how can I do that without writing domain name?

Comment: you can use `include` function

Comment: @ChetanAmeta `include()` also needs a path.

Comment: yes it requires physical path of file and this path depend in which script you require it.. for example you want to include it a index.php of root then your path will be `dirname(__FILE__).'/folder1/folder2/scriptname.php'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In script 2 You can use:

```
file_get_contents("../folder2/script1.php");
```

Or you can also include script 1 in script 2:

```
include("../folder2/script1.php");
```

Better approach is to create a class.

Comment: Please edit your answer and write this path `../folder1/folder2/script1.php`